# Alternatives to Kendo UI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have used some Kendo UI controls before on previous projects, but now i am on a project that utilizes responsive web design methodologies. The primary focus is tablets.
The thing is, the standard kendo ui web control are not very touch/mobile friendly by default.

So, are there any other good alternatives, that are responsive and touch/mobile friendly? I just want to know my options before trying to pull Kendo UI apart (more time consuming, compared to finding alternatives).

Having MVC compatible .NET controls is a plus.

Comment: Perhaps off topic but useful question.  Fascist :)

Comment: This list by Cody Lindley, even though done a while ago, is still helpful. http://codylindley.com/jqueryuiwidgets/

Answer (score 2):

according to me one of the alternative is Syncfusion which is quite similar to kendo and our company has used it previously and now we r having licence of kendo..

im attaching the link below :-

http://www.syncfusion.com/